# How to convert this VBA Excel code to C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I am trying to convert excel VBA code to c#. This code must be executed outside excel and I am going to convert my excel macros to do so. Here is the code to convert

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85
    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Cells.Select
```

Here is what I got so far:

```
var excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
excelApp.Visible = true;
excelApp.ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85;
excelApp.Range["A1"].Select();
```

I cannot figure out the rest below the `Range("A1").Select`. Any help on this

Comment: C# doesn't support `with`, so just do `Selection.HorizontalAlign = xlCenter;`, `Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom;`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The with statement is a VB thing only, with c# you have to create a variable and call each of the properties from that variable explicitly

```
ActiveWindow.Zoom = 85;
Range["A1"].Select();
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select();
Selection.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter;
Selection.VerticalAlignment = xlBottom;
Selection.WrapText = true;
Selection.Orientation = 0;
Selection.AddIndent = false;
Selection.IndentLevel = 0;
Selection.ShrinkToFit = false;
Selection.ReadingOrder = xlContext;
Selection.MergeCells = false;
Cells.Select();
```

(this is just a sample, do adjust your COM handling as required)

EDIT: Changed brackets to square brackets one the second line.

Comment: You're forgetting to use brackets - `Range["A1"]...`

Answer (score 0):

You need the namespace "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel".

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

MyClass{
...
    var app = new Application { Visible = true, ScreenUpdating = true, DisplayAlerts = false }; 
    Workbook book = app.Workbooks.Open(path); //path is the fullFileName as string
    Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[1];
    Range range = sheet.get_Range("A1", "A1");
    range.Select();
    range.HorizontalAlignment = Constants.xlCenter;
    range.VerticalAlignment = Constants.xlBottom;
    range.WrapText = true;
    range.Orientation = 0;
    range.AddIndent = false;
    range.IndentLevel = 0;
    range.ShrinkToFit = false;
    range.ReadingOrder = Constants.xlContext;
    range.MergeCells = false;
}
```

Enjoy it!